# Remove webjars version from url

Tags: javascript, java, maven, jsp, webjars

We are using webjars with maven in our project.
So we have hundreds of JSPs with code like this:

```
<%--JSP CODE--%>
<script src="<c:url value="/webjars/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
.........
```

And as you can guess it's a cumbersome work to update to newer versions of webjars. So I'm looking for the solution which will allow me to import scripts like this:

```
<%--JSP CODE--%>
<script src="<c:url value="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
.........
```

Basically I want to remove a webjar version from url.
Can you propose nice and simple solution for this problem?

So far I come up with resource servlet which can guess which file to return by the url. But this solution involves full resource scanning at the start of an application.

Comment: If you use minifying you can create those js files into a separate folder and with a name which does not contain the version...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [webjars-locator](https://github.com/webjars/webjars-locator) project, you can use it to create proper request controller.

In case of using `Spring MVC` this would be:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/webjarslocator/{webjar}/**")
public ResponseEntity locateWebjarAsset(@PathVariable String webjar, HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        String mvcPrefix = "/webjarslocator/" + webjar + "/"; // This prefix must match the mapping path!
        String mvcPath = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
        String fullPath = assetLocator.getFullPath(webjar, mvcPath.substring(mvcPrefix.length()));
        return new ResponseEntity(new ClassPathResource(fullPath), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: This is the code from `WebJars` [documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) (section `Making dependencies version agnostic`).

In this case you can ask for js libraries in following way:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/webjarslocator/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

Please note that there's no version in this url.

You can also try to optimize this requests (and consequently - filesystem scans) by using cache, but I am almost sure that some kind of cache is already involved in `webjars-locator` (I haven't checked that).

Comment: you can put an example that does not use `spring` or any other framework only `maven`???